# how to add id to a autogenerafted text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop up menu(kendo) in that there is a text box which created by Kendo

```
< input name="Fname" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:Fname >
```

I want to give it an id,since its generated by Kendo how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element = document.getElementsByName("Fname")`

here you have your element

`element.id = "MortDeLol"`

here you set your Id